# What is the max input size of an index in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to store a number 10<sup>8</sup> as an index in a map. Is it possible? If yes, what is the max value of the index we can use in a map?

Comment: Are you referring to an `std::map`?

Comment: Maps don't take indexes, they take keys.

Comment: The max value of the key for a map would be the max value of the data type you use as the key.

Comment: `std::uint64_t` can store it no problem.

Comment: General advice - when in doubt, convert your number to string. :)

Comment: I didnt understand @Nanev

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` stores entries looked up by keys, not by indexes.  It is not an array.

The maximum value you can use for a key is determined by whatever data type you decide to use for the key.  For instance, 10<sup>8</sup> will easily fit in a `std::(u)int32_t` (or larger) integer type, which has a max value of `2147483647` (signed, 2<sup>31</sup>-1) or `4294967295` (unsigned, 2<sup>32</sup>-1).  You can use `std::numeric_limits::max()` to determine the max value of any numeric type.

The `std::map::max_size()` method returns the maximum number of entries (ie, unique keys) that can be stored in the map, regardless of their values.  For instance, if you stored  key `0` and key `100000000` (10<sup>8</sup>), there would only be 2 keys in the map, not 100000001 keys.

Unlike an indexed array, the values of the keys for a `std::map` matter only for uniqueness, not for count.

Comment: Sry I typed index I meant keys of numbers(like int long long). And Thanks alot for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I will write it as an answer, since comment does not have fine code formatting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, string> my_map;
    int whatever_number = 100000000;

    string key = to_string(whatever_number);

    my_map[key] = "Hello World!\n";

    cout << my_map[key];
}
```

Comment: This isn't really answering the question, since he asked about using "a number", not a string as the key. Your example is much better by just have a map of <int, string> and using `whatever_number`directly as key.